# Doing tasks with my RFID Reader plugged into my Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: python, raspberry-pi4, rfid

I have an RFID reader connected to my Raspberry Pi 4, and it works but how do I do stuff based on the text that is on the RFID chip I have tried this python script but why don't the script work and there is no error. On the Chip is the word Test, and it works if I just let it print out the line 8, but I can't get the script to print the test print in line 10

```
#i/usr/bin/env/ python3
    import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

    from mfrc522 import SimpleMFRC522
    reader = SimpleMFRC522()
    try:
       id, text = reader.read()
        #print(id)
        #print(text)
        if text == "Test":
            print("it worked")
    finally:
        GPIO.cleanup()
```